# how to find number of times a column is not null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have a bunch of columns in a mysql table whose names begin with 'X_' (for example: X_N, X_Pad, X_Server etc). Now, these columns can be null.

I want to find out which column beginning with 'X_' is NOT NULL the most.

Answer (score 3):

> [`COUNT(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement.

The following query will return not-null counts for each column:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)     AS Total,
COUNT(X_N)   AS NNC_N,
COUNT(X_Pad) AS NNC_Pad
FROM table;
```

---

You can use this query to get the list of matching columns from a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
AND   TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
AND   COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'x\_%';

-- Output:
-- X_N
-- X_Pad
-- X_Server
```

You can use this query to build a query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT('COUNT(`', COLUMN_NAME, '`) AS `NNC of ', COLUMN_NAME, '`'), ' FROM `', TABLE_NAME, '`')
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
AND   TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
AND   COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'x\_%';

-- Output (added whitespace for readability):
-- SELECT
-- COUNT(`X_N`)      AS `NNC of X_N`,
-- COUNT(`X_Pad`)    AS `NNC of X_Pad`,
-- COUNT(`X_Server`) AS `NNC of X_Server`
-- FROM `<table_name>`
```

Alternate:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT \'', COLUMN_NAME, '\' AS `Col`, COUNT(`', COLUMN_NAME , '`) AS `NNC` FROM `', TABLE_NAME , '`' SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
AND   TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
AND   COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'x\_%';

-- Output (added whitespace for readability):
-- SELECT 'X_N'      AS `Col`, COUNT(`X_N`)      AS `NNC` FROM `<table_name>` UNION ALL 
-- SELECT 'X_Pad'    AS `Col`, COUNT(`X_Pad`)    AS `NNC` FROM `<table_name>` UNION ALL 
-- SELECT 'X_Server' AS `Col`, COUNT(`X_Server`) AS `NNC` FROM `<table_name>`
```

Comment: And to find out, which one is the most: `SELECT GREATEST(COUNT(X_N), COUNT(X_Pad), ...) FROM table`

Comment: The problem is that there are a large no of 'X_' columns.
If I were to follow ur solution, i would have to manually enter each column. Is there a shorter way?
we can use "LIKE 'X_'" or something in our querry.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in MySQL to create queries dynamically. You can query table meta data to grab list of columns, edit the list in excel and build the actual query. See revised answer.

Comment: *‘…and `TRIM` to remove the unnecessary union all’* – with GROUP_CONCAT() you wouldn't need to trim anything, because it would insert the delimiter only between the items.

Comment: @AndriyM... you're right, didn't realize that it is much easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

select count(X_N), count(X_Pad), count(X_Server) from db.tbl;

can be ok.

If you just need a method to generate this SQL, you can use

```
SELECT CONCAT("select ", GROUP_CONCAT("count(",column_name, ")"), " from ", table_schema, '.', table_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='db' AND table_name='tbl' AND column_name LIKE 'X\_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? (untested)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM My_Table WHERE X_1 != NULL) as x1,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM My_Table WHERE X_2 != NULL) as x2,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM My_Table WHERE X_3 != NULL) as x3,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM My_Table WHERE X_4 != NULL) as x4;
```

Comment: I believe COUNT() doesn't count null values so the != null may not be required.